# How to make sure that file contents were not modified during read operation in NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, macos, filesystems

Suppose we have a file (less than 1MiB). This file can be modified (or deleted) by some program (git) from time to time. Also this file is being read by a Node application from time to time.
How to make sure that file contents that have been read by the Node application are in a consistent state?
Here's an example of what I'm afraid might happen.

1. Initial state of the file (A, B, C are just different parts of the file): `ABC`.
2. Node app reads file stats (mtimeMs).
3. Node app starts reading the file and reads `A`.
4. Other process starts writing to the file and writes to `A` making it `A*` and to `B` making it `B*` (file state: `A*B*C`).
5. Node app reads `B*` and `C`.
6. Node app reads file stats (mtimeMs).
7. Other process writes to `C` making it `C*` (file state: `A*B*C*`).
8. OS writes new file modification time.

As a result the Node application will get inconsistent file state `AB*C` while both mtimeMs read before and after operation are the same.
Note: temporarily blocking write operations to the file is not an option.

Comment: The solution is to let the file system prevent incompatible concurrent accesses. Preemptively rejecting the solution isn't going to get you any closer to that solution.

Comment: @IInspectable if you're talking about blocking write operations then this is not an option because the process that writes to the file is git and git updates must never fail just because the Node app is currently reading from this file.  
If you're talking about some other mechanism then I'd like to hear about that more.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a hash from the string you read and then after the file, compare those, if they are the same, you know the data is the same, if not you retry till it does.

I don't know if a hash from a string and the hash from the file would be the same tho... Then you could take a hash from the file before and after you read the data, if they are different, have your code retry until they aren't.

example: https://gist.github.com/GuillermoPena/9233069

Comment: The problems I see with this approach are the following: a) the whole file must be read into memory; b) the operation is expensive (compute hash from file stream, read file into memory, compute hash). So this doesn't scale well. In reality there will be dozens such files that will be read at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

You could start watching the file you are reading, taking appropriate action when it does.

https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener